# Circle and Sphere in OpenGL ES

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, opengl-es

In OpenGL ES 1.1 (using Objective-C), what is the easiest way to create a circle, and for a sphere? I would prefer for it to be easy to implement, as I am new to OpenGL.

Thanks
jrtc27

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://iphonedevelopment.blogspot.com/2009/05/procedural-spheres-in-opengl-es.html

That site has some fantastic basics tutorials for openGL ES too. Note: it's not an efficient way to do it, but since you asked for easy rather than efficient, you might be interested.

Comment: This has been going for so long, so I am just going to accept it. It is not quite what I was after, but I no longer need it :) Thanks anyway

Comment: The link works, but the link embedded in the link (the only way to access the code) is broken. Do you have any follow-up?